# Split file to upload it via HTTP

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, multipart

I am working on a [react](/questions/tagged/react) / [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) (*[express](/questions/tagged/express)*) stack. In this project, I have to upload large binary file (*~150mb*) from the client to server. Everything went well until the production deployment. Due to a proxy limitation (*10mb*) our request are blocked.

I have read a lot the past few days regarding splitting files and multipart. Also tried a lot (*byte-range etc.*) without success, and without understanding what I did.

Can someone have any idea about how to split files client side and reconstitute it in server side and doing the same thing in the other way?

Thanks in advance and excuse my mistake if any.

Comment: Have you looked into streaming the file upload?

Comment: or even have a multipart form (multipart in the sense it can know which part of the fil you are uploading at each time called, eg now uploading part 2 of 5). Then simply split the file in client by whichever means, upload individual parts and let the server concatenate the parts into a whole file